# Python-pptx loading slide content from csv

Tags: python-pptx

Looking to insert text, images, etc. from a CSV file into a PowerPoint presentation using Python-pptx. So the idea is each line in a CSV would have title, text, image that I could update then run Python-pptx to pull from the CSV to populate each slide with the content.  I read that "A typical use would be generating a customized PowerPoint presentation from database content".  I'm a total Python/programming nube and apologize for this basic question but I've searched and can't find any info or basic tutorial on this subject. I think it might be placeholder but not sure.

Comment: code you post some code, expected input and output. In this case it would be much more easier to help. A request for general advice is considered of topic as it attracts oppinionated and low quality answers, as well as spam. I appreciate your understanding in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you consult the documentation, especially this Getting Started page:
https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html

If what you find there doesn't make sense to you, then you probably need to start with a Python programming tutorial.

Becoming a programmer, even a beginning programmer takes earnest study and practice (in the sense of "doing"). It's definitely not something that would fit as a "quick answer".

I'd see if you can follow-along with the quickstart tutorial I linked to and then see how you can adapt what you learned to the presentation generation project you have, searching for individual specific answers as you encounter them. Many of those answers will be somewhere here in StackOverflow, but there are many other resources as well; Google is a find friend indeed in your situation.